# Rundll32.exe javascript

Tags: javascript, mshtml, rundll32

I've just (August 2014) seen a report of a program that uses the command line

```
rundll32.exe javascript:"\..\mshtml,RunHTMLApplication"
```

How does that work? I thought the first parameter was supposed to be the name of a DLL (mshtml), but how does rundll32 parse that command line?

rundll reference: 
    http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787

Comment: I'm curious as to how this is a down-voted question. This is a fascinating question. It is not necessarily something you'd run into every day writing programs, but is definitely an opportunity for someone to provide a detailed explanation of some very low-level stuff in Windows-land. (as @TheQwerty did below)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a great explanation of this here: http://thisissecurity.net/2014/08/20/poweliks-command-line-confusion/

To summarize using the same example of:

```
rundll32.exe javascript:"\..\mshtml,RunHTMLApplication ";alert('foo');
```

1. **RunDll32**

   1. Parses the command and decides the intended DLL is: `javascript:"\..\mshtml`
   2. Fails at loading that as an absolute path.
   3. Fails to find a match in the working directory or on the path.
   4. Fails to find a manifest `javascript:"\..\mshtml.manifest`for the module.
   5. Calls *LoadLibrary*
2. **LoadLibrary**

   1. Adds the extension and attempts to load `javascript:"\..\mshtml.dll`
   2. Treats this as relative, so it goes up from the fake `javascript:"\` directory.
   3. Searches for `mshtml.dll` which it finds in the System directory.
   4. Loads the DLL using *RunHTMLApplication* as the entry point.
3. **RunHTMLApplication**

   1. Attempts to execute the command `";alert('foo');`
   2. As that's invalid Javascript it calls *GetCommandLine* for the original command which returns `javascript:"\..\mshtml,RunHTMLApplication ";alert('foo');`
   3. Attempts to open this URI so it asks the system how to handle the *javascript* protocol which is typically set to *Microsoft HTML Javascript Pluggable Protocol* in the registry.
   4. Then executes the Javascript: `"..\mshtml,RunHTMLApplication ";alert('foo');`
4. **Javascript**

   1. The first statement creates a string and does nothing with it which is valid enough to not cause an error.
   2. Continues executing the rest of the script.

Comment: Either a very clever bit of programming, or an unutterable kludge, but exceptional all the same. Either way, not a supported technique and likely to get blocked soon.

Comment: Still works today on updated windows 10. Not likely to be fixed any soon.

Comment: Where is `RunHTMLApplication` documented ?

Comment: @ChefGladiator the invalid JavaScript starts with the double quotes, so it's technically an unclosed string. `RunHTMLApplication` is an undocumented method used by `mshta.exe` for opening hta files. The link in the answer does a much better job of explaining this.

Comment: Thanks @TheQwerty ... if you paste that string into the browser address bar, it will be executed with no complaints. Thus I might dare to call it a valid javascript code. This is part of the unfortunate "Windows Scripting Host" subsystem. I find it very useful.